# Classes and Objects. Getting 0.0 as answer when calculating price. - JAVA

Tags: java, oop

I'm working out a question from a labsheet but i'm only getting 0.0 as answer when running the program. I can't find out what's wrong please help.

The question:

Implement a class Pizza with attribute diameter (in cm), cost_sq_cm (cost per square cm) and area. Its methods are:

 • Constructor to create an object of type Pizza with a given diameter and given price_sq_cm. 

• Mutator and accessor methods for diameter and cost_sq_cm. 

• calcArea to calculate the area of a given pizza. 

• getPrice to calculate and return the price of a pizza.

Write a class TestPizza with a main method that declares an object of type Pizza with a user inputted diameter and user-­‐inputted cost_sq_cm of a circular pizza, and display the price of the pizza.

The Pizza class:

```
package Number3;

public class Pizza {
private int diameter;
private float cost_sq_cm;
private double area;
private double price;

public Pizza() //default constructor
{
    diameter = 0;
    cost_sq_cm = 0;
    area = 0;
    price = 0;
}

public Pizza(int d,float cost,double a,double p) //overloaded constructor
{
    d = diameter;
    cost = cost_sq_cm;
    a = area;
    p = price;  
}

public void Constructor() //method
{
    Pizza P = new Pizza();
}

public void setDiameter(int d) //mutator
{
    d = diameter;
}

public int getDiameter() //accessor
{
    return diameter;
}

public void setCost(float c)
{
    c = cost_sq_cm;
}

public float getCost()
{
    return cost_sq_cm;
}

public double calcArea()
{
    area = 3.142 * (diameter * diameter);
    return area;
}

public double getPrice()
{ 
    price = area * cost_sq_cm;
    return price;
}

public void display()
{
    System.out.print("The area is: "+this.price);
}
}
```

TestPizza:

```
package Number3;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestPizza {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    float area = 0;
    Pizza P = new Pizza();

    int d; float c,a = 0;
    System.out.print("Enter a value for the diameter: ");
    d = input.nextInt();
    P.setDiameter(d);

    System.out.print("Enter a value for the cost: ");
    c = input.nextFloat();
    P.setCost(c);

    P.display();    
}

}
```

I'm new to JAVA. Please be lenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
System.out.print("The area is: "+this.price);
```

Use:

```
System.out.print("The area is: "+this.getPrice());
```

You need to calculate area as well. So in your main method call it like:

```
P.calcArea();//to calculate area
```

You initialised price as 0, when you called `new Pizza()` and you never called getPrice which is where you calculate the price.

Also change your setter for cost from:

```
public void setCost(float c) {
   c = cost_sq_cm;
}
```

To

```
public void setCost(float c) {
    cost_sq_cm = c;
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it is still displaying 0.0 as answer.

Comment: I added P.calcArea as well as P.getPrice(). I also modified  this.price to this,getPrice() but i'm still getting 0.0 as answer. Can you try to run this program and see whether you are getting the answer?

Comment: What?! This simple error caused it not to work. lol I'll bear that in mind now. Variable  = value. It's working fine now.

Answer (score 3):

You should multiply cost per square centimeter times area to get price.    You'll get zero if either one is equal to zero.  I see where you've set diameter, but not area.

You set diameter, but you don't calculate area when you set it.

```
public void setDiameter(int d) //mutator; lose this comment.  worthless clutter.
{
    d = diameter;
    area = calcArea();
}
```

I'd recommend following the Java idiom.  Don't write a `display()` method; better to override `toString()`.

I'd write it this way:

```
package cruft;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

/**
 * Pizza
 * @author Michael
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28658669/classes-and-objects-getting-0-0-as-answer-when-calculating-price-java
 * @since 2/22/2015 12:27 PM
 */
public class Pizza {

    private static final int DEFAULT_DIAMETER = 38;
    private static final double DEFAULT_COST = 15.0;
    private static final double DEFAULT_COST_PER_AREA = 0.013226;     // 15 euro for a 38 cm diameter pizza
    private static final NumberFormat DEFAULT_FORMAT = new DecimalFormat("#.####");

    private final int diameter;
    private final double costPerArea;
    private final double price;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int diameter = ((args.length > 0) ? Integer.valueOf(args[0]) : DEFAULT_DIAMETER);
        double costPerArea = ((args.length > 1) ? Double.valueOf(args[1]) : DEFAULT_COST_PER_AREA);
        Pizza pizza = new Pizza(diameter, costPerArea);
        System.out.println(pizza);
    }

    public Pizza(int diameter, double costPerArea) {
        if (diameter <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("diameter must be positive");
        if (costPerArea <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("cost per area must be positive");
        this.diameter = diameter;
        this.costPerArea = costPerArea;
        this.price = this.costPerArea*this.calculateArea();
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    private double calculateArea() {
        return Math.PI*this.diameter*this.diameter/4.0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Pizza{");
        sb.append("diameter=").append(diameter);
        sb.append(", costPerArea=").append(DEFAULT_FORMAT.format(costPerArea));
        sb.append(", price=").append(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(getPrice()));
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it is still displaying 0.0 as answer.

Comment: Even when i don't set area = calcArea() it displays the answer. Why is it important?

Comment: Why is what important?  Getting an answer that makes sense?

Comment: Nope why should i set area = calcArea() ?

Answer (score 1):

For setting a field or another value it is

```
variable = value;
```

so

```
diameter = d;
```

Comment: ...and the other fields as well.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `setCost` and `setDiameter` methods need to be changed,

From

```
d = diameter;
```

To

```
this.diameter = d;
```